# Can I position a button next to a pre?

Tags: html, css, button

I have some HTML generated from a text editor macro. The output looks something like this:

```
<div class='source-block'>

  <div class="src-container">
    <pre class="src bash">sudo apt update</pre>
  </div>

  <button class='copyBtn' name=btn_e320edcae3214004ba6339711d50024a>copy</button>

</div>
```

The only CSS I currently have applied to any of these elements so far is on the `pre`:

```
pre {
    padding: 8pt;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 1.2em;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

pre.src {
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-top: 1.2em;
}
```

I am trying to place my `copyBtn` directly to the right of the `<pre>`. Because of the way this text editor macro works, I cannot put the button *inside* the `src-container`, which is "automagically" generated. However, I can move the button before or after the `src-container` div.

Can I achieve this with CSS? I've tried some stuff using `float` with `:last-child` and `z-index` but no success... Is this even possible given the macro limitation (i.e., I cannot easily place HTML inside this `src-container` class)?

Thanks!

Comment: yes this is possible, could you provide us with the css applied to the elements?, it is really usefull to know what css `.source-block` and `.src-container` have

Comment: The snippet you provide can be placed in one line with a simple ".src-container {
  float: left
}", but you will already have some CSS on your page that might overrule this. So without a minimal working example from your side it will be hard to help.

Comment: The problem I can't seem to get around is that the button is showing up below the pre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flexbox to position the flow of the child element within the `source-block` (parent). You can use this to put them next to each other and position the vertical position with `align-items: center;`

More about flexbox here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox

Can I use Flexbox (browser support):
https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

```css
/* changed CSS */
.source-block {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  align-content:flex-start;
}

/* provided CSS*/
pre {
    padding: 8pt;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 1.2em;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

pre.src {
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-top: 1.2em;
}

/* misc styling */
.copyBtn {
  margin-top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="source-block">

  <div class="src-container">
    <pre class="src bash">sudo apt update</pre>
  </div>

  <button class='copyBtn' name=btn_e320edcae3214004ba6339711d50024a>copy</button>

</div>
```

Comment: This works for me! Thanks! Do you know if I can also align the button to the start of the `pre` with flex? i.e., put the button towards the top for a large `source-block`.

Comment: You can play a little with `align-self` and `align-items`. shouldn't be too hard there are some great resources about flexbox online :-)

Answer (score 0):

> Set all the class named src-container.

```
<style>
  .src-container {
    dispay:inline;
  }
</style>
```

> Or, set the single button.

```
  button[name="******"] {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Could you also add an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to use float: left on the src-container to make the button go to the right of it. You could also use float:right on the copyBtn. These make the block elements go next to each other.

```css
pre {
    padding: 8pt;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 1.2em;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
pre.src {
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-top: 1.2em;
}
.src-container {
  float: left
}
```

```html
<div class='source-block'>

  <div class="src-container">
    <pre class="src bash">sudo apt update</pre>
  </div>

  <button class='copyBtn' name=btn_e320edcae3214004ba6339711d50024a>copy</button>

</div>
```

Comment: I just updated my question with some additional css that's already applied on my pre. Does this change your answer? I'm having some difficulty stripping out all the non-relevant HTML/CSS and making a small reproducible, and accurate, example.

Comment: I added the css from your question to the answer, but the copy button is still next to the container, although the height is a bit different due to the padding-top: 1.2em;

Did you check if the float:left works on your page?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution: move the button before the `.src-container` and float it.

```
.copyBtn {
    float: right;
}
```

Second solution: don't need to move the button, just position it absolutely, adjusting the top position to where you see fit. Only requirement is making sure the element that contains all these (typically the `body`) should have `position` set (usually so, but not always).

```
.copyBtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px; right: 10px;
}
```

There are more advanced techniques, like auto aligning the button, but as your layout is clearly known, this should do enough for your purpose.